# Nginx configuration Issue

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-location

**I am using nginx-1.10.3 as a load balancer**. In my architecture, I have two servers-

1. Hostname - sal15062hkb152, IP Address - 172.15.54.116
2. Hostname - sal15062hkb184, IP Address - 172.15.54.105

I want both should work in active-passive mode with **nginx**. My application is running on both servers and client can access my application using URL -

https://sal15062hkb152/views or https://sal15062hkb184/views

My nginx.conf is -

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  sal15062hkb152;

        #http://sal15062hkb152/oneview/;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {

        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  sal15062hkb152;

        #ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        #ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

        ssl_certificate       iperspective.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key   iperspective.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   http://oneview;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to access https://sal15062hkb152/views but I am getting "**404 Not Found**" in browser. I believe, my nginx.conf file configuration is not correct. Please let me know proper configuration for my nginx.conf file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a default virtual server for 80 and 443 otherwise specific configurations wont work.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name _; # for every server without specific configuration
    return 404; # doesnt matter
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name _; # for every server without configuration
    return 404; # doesnt matter
}
```

**Edit:** By the way when you got the stuff working, I highly recommend you to have a look at [this documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) about secure ssl configuration.

They are based on [this article](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified nginx.conf file as you suggested but it is not working. Can you plz let me know, what should i do exact changes in my nginx.conf, which can satisfy my requirement. Thanks